# iPhone 4: Play audio while on call

Tags: iphone-4

I have developed an application which will play audio when call is on. And the person on opposite side can hear it.
It works fine with pre iphone4. But its not working with iphone4.

After some search, I found that iPhone4 considers that audio sound as noise and filters it out. Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance.